# web.config error

Tags: iis-7, web-config, dotnetnuke

I have a site in DNN which I transferred to another server. After I configure everything on my IIS and configure the site I get the following error and I see 500 Internal Server error on browser.

[image]

What could be wrong?

```
<configuration>

<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="dotnetnuke">

      <section name="data" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="logging" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="scheduling" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="htmlEditor" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="navigationControl" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="searchIndex" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="searchDataStore" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="friendlyUrl" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="caching" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="authentication" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="members" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="roles" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="profiles" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="permissions" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="moduleCaching" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="outputCaching" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="sitemap" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web">
      <section name="neatUpload" type="Brettle.Web.NeatUpload.ConfigSectionHandler, Brettle.Web.NeatUpload" allowLocation="true" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;User ID=;Password=" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>

    <add key="SiteSqlServer" value="Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;User ID=;Password=" />

    <add key="InstallTemplate" value="DotNetNuke.install.config" />
    <add key="AutoUpgrade" value="true" />
    <add key="UseInstallWizard" value="true" />
    <add key="InstallMemberRole" value="true" />
    <add key="ShowMissingKeys" value="false" />
    <add key="EnableCachePersistence" value="false" />
    <add key="HostHeader" value="" />
        <add key="RemoveAngleBrackets" value="false" />
          <add key="PersistentCookieTimeout" value="0" />

    <add key="InstallationDate" value="11/19/2010" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5" />
        <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true" />
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false" />
      </compiler>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider,System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5" />
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false" />
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="Compression" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.Compression.CompressionModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="RequestFilter" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.RequestFilter.RequestFilterModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="UrlRewrite" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.UrlRewriteModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="Exception" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.Exceptions.ExceptionModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="UsersOnline" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.UsersOnline.UsersOnlineModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="DNNMembership" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.Membership.MembershipModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="Personalization" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.Personalization.PersonalizationModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="Analytics" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.Analytics.AnalyticsModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="UploadHttpModule" type="Brettle.Web.NeatUpload.UploadHttpModule, Brettle.Web.NeatUpload" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
      <add name="LogoffHandler*" path="Logoff.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Authentication.LogOffHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
      <add name="RSSHandler" path="RSS.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Syndication.RssHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
      <add name="LinkClickHandler" path="LinkClick.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.FileSystem.FileServerHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
      <add name="CaptchaHandler" path="*.captcha.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.UI.WebControls.CaptchaHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add name="ScriptResource" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add name="UserProfilePageHandler" verb="*" path="User.aspx" type="DotNetNuke.Services.UserProfile.UserProfilePageHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
      <add name="RadProgressHandler" verb="*" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.RadUploadProgressHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" />
      <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" />
      <add name="SitemapHandler" path="Sitemap.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Sitemap.SitemapHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
      <add name="HtmTemplateFileHandler" verb="*" path="*.htmtemplate" type="DotNetNuke.HtmlEditor.TelerikEditorProvider.HtmTemplateFileHandler, DotNetNuke.HtmlEditor.TelerikEditorProvider" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^tejgyan.org$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.tejgyan.org/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <machineKey validationKey="58F0C768C126049FCABCB180F3B783623F7ABC6E" decryptionKey="CFD5DE474C9CBE74C4A772B5895E97C85A8339F550B9C3A9" decryption="3DES" validation="SHA1" />

    <httpModules>

      <add name="Compression" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.Compression.CompressionModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" />
      <add name="RequestFilter" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.RequestFilter.RequestFilterModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" />
      <add name="UrlRewrite" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.UrlRewriteModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" />
      <add name="Exception" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.Exceptions.ExceptionModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" />
      <add name="UsersOnline" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.UsersOnline.UsersOnlineModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" />
      <add name="DNNMembership" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.Membership.MembershipModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" />
      <add name="Personalization" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.Personalization.PersonalizationModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" />
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add name="Analytics" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.Analytics.AnalyticsModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" />
      <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule, Telerik.Web.UI" />
      <add name="UploadHttpModule" type="Brettle.Web.NeatUpload.UploadHttpModule, Brettle.Web.NeatUpload" />
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>

      <add verb="*" path="*.captcha.aspx" type="DotNetNuke.UI.WebControls.CaptchaHandler, DotNetNuke" />

      <add verb="*" path="LinkClick.aspx" type="DotNetNuke.Services.FileSystem.FileServerHandler, DotNetNuke" />

      <add verb="*" path="RSS.aspx" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Syndication.RssHandler, DotNetNuke" />

      <add verb="*" path="Logoff.aspx" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Authentication.LogOffHandler, DotNetNuke" />

      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add verb="*" path="User.aspx" type="DotNetNuke.Services.UserProfile.UserProfilePageHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <add verb="*" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.RadUploadProgressHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" />
      <add verb="*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" validate="false" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" />
      <add verb="*" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" validate="true" />
      <add verb="*" path="Sitemap.aspx" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Sitemap.SitemapHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <add verb="*" path="*.htmtemplate" type="DotNetNuke.HtmlEditor.TelerikEditorProvider.HtmTemplateFileHandler, DotNetNuke.HtmlEditor.TelerikEditorProvider" />
    </httpHandlers>


    <compilation strict="false" defaultLanguage="c#">
      <buildProviders>
        <remove extension=".resx" />
        <remove extension=".resources" />
      </buildProviders>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Management, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>

    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".DOTNETNUKE" protection="All" timeout="60" cookieless="UseCookies" />
    </authentication>


    <httpRuntime useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" maxRequestLength="102400" requestLengthDiskThreshold="102400" executionTimeout="30000" />
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" domain="" />

    <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="af-ZA" requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" fileEncoding="UTF-8" />


    <pages validateRequest="false" enableViewStateMac="true" enableEventValidation="false">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.ComponentModel" />
        <add namespace="System.Data" />
        <add namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add namespace="System.Drawing" />
        <add namespace="Microsoft.VisualBasic" />
        <add namespace="System.Globalization" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Services.Localization" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Entities.Users" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Common" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Data" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Framework" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Modules" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Security" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Services" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.UI" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions" />
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <!-- ASP.NET 2 Membership/Profile/Role and AnonymousAuthentication Providers -->
    <!-- anonymousIdentification configuration:
          enabled="[true|false]"                              Feature is enabled?
          cookieName=".ASPXANONYMOUS"                         Cookie Name
          cookieTimeout="100000"                              Cookie Timeout in minutes
          cookiePath="/"                                      Cookie Path
          cookieRequireSSL="[true|false]"                     Set Secure bit in Cookie
          cookieSlidingExpiration="[true|false]"              Reissue expiring cookies?
          cookieProtection="[None|Validation|Encryption|All]" How to protect cookies from being read/tampered
          domain="[domain]"                                   Enables output of the "domain" cookie attribute set to the specified value
        -->
    <anonymousIdentification enabled="true" cookieName=".ASPXANONYMOUS" cookieTimeout="100000" cookiePath="/" cookieRequireSSL="false" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" cookieProtection="None" domain="" />
    <membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <!-- Configuration for AspNetSqlMembershipProvider:
                connectionStringName="string"               Name corresponding to the entry in <connectionStrings> section where the connection string for the provider is specified
                maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="int"            The number of failed password attempts, or failed password answer attempts that are allowed before locking out a user?s account
                passwordAttemptWindow="int"                 The time window, in minutes, during which failed password attempts and failed password answer attempts are tracked
                enablePasswordRetrieval="[true|false]"      Should the provider support password retrievals
                enablePasswordReset="[true|false]"          Should the provider support password resets
                requiresQuestionAndAnswer="[true|false]"    Should the provider require Q & A
                minRequiredPasswordLength="int"             The minimum password length
                minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="int"  The minimum number of non-alphanumeric characters
                applicationName="string"                    Optional string to identity the application: defaults to Application Metabase path
                requiresUniqueEmail="[true|false]"          Should the provider require a unique email to be specified
                passwordFormat="[Clear|Hashed|Encrypted]"   Storage format for the password: Hashed (SHA1), Clear or Encrypted (Triple-DES)
                description="string"                        Description of what the provider does
                -->
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="SiteSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Encrypted" applicationName="DotNetNuke" description="Stores and retrieves membership data from the local Microsoft SQL Server database" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <neatUpload useHttpModule="true" maxRequestLength="102400" defaultProvider="FilesystemUploadStorageProvider" maxNormalRequestLength="8192">
      <providers>
        <add name="FilesystemUploadStorageProvider" type="Brettle.Web.NeatUpload.FilesystemUploadStorageProvider, Brettle.Web.NeatUpload" />
      </providers>
    </neatUpload>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="bin;bin\HttpModules;bin\Providers;bin\Modules;bin\Support;" />
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Web.UI" publicKeyToken="121fae78165ba3d4" />

        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2008.0.0.0-2020.0.0.0" newVersion="2010.02.0929.35" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <dotnetnuke>
    <htmlEditor defaultProvider="TelerikEditorProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />


        <add name="TelerikEditorProvider" type="DotNetNuke.HtmlEditor.TelerikEditorProvider.EditorProvider, DotNetNuke.HtmlEditor.TelerikEditorProvider" providerPath="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/" toolsFile="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/Config/ToolsDefault.xml" configFile="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/Config/ConfigDefault.xml" FilterHostExtensions="True" />
      </providers>
    </htmlEditor>
    <navigationControl defaultProvider="DNNMenuNavigationProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="DNNDropDownNavigationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.NavigationControl.DNNDropDownNavigationProvider, DotNetNuke.DNNDropDownNavigationProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\NavigationProviders\DNNDropDownNavigationProvider\" />
        <add name="ASP2MenuNavigationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.NavigationControl.ASP2MenuNavigationProvider, DotNetNuke.ASP2MenuNavigationProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\NavigationProviders\ASP2MenuNavigationProvider\" />
        <add name="DNNMenuNavigationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.NavigationControl.DNNMenuNavigationProvider, DotNetNuke.DNNMenuNavigationProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\NavigationProviders\DNNMenuNavigationProvider\" />
        <add name="DNNTreeNavigationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.NavigationControl.DNNTreeNavigationProvider, DotNetNuke.DNNTreeNavigationProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\NavigationProviders\DNNTreeNavigationProvider\" />
        <add name="SolpartMenuNavigationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.NavigationControl.SolpartMenuNavigationProvider, DotNetNuke.SolpartMenuNavigationProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\NavigationProviders\SolpartMenuNavigationProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </navigationControl>
    <searchIndex defaultProvider="ModuleIndexProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="ModuleIndexProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Search.ModuleIndexer, DotNetNuke.Search.Index" providerPath="~\Providers\SearchProviders\ModuleIndexer\" />
      </providers>
    </searchIndex>
    <searchDataStore defaultProvider="SearchDataStoreProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SearchDataStoreProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Search.SearchDataStore, DotNetNuke.Search.DataStore" providerPath="~\Providers\SearchProviders\SearchDataStore\" />
      </providers>
    </searchDataStore>
    <data defaultProvider="SqlDataProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SqlDataProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke.SqlDataProvider" connectionStringName="SiteSqlServer" upgradeConnectionString="" providerPath="~\Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider\" objectQualifier="" databaseOwner="tejgyanorg" />
      </providers>
    </data>
    <logging defaultProvider="DBLoggingProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="DBLoggingProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Log.EventLog.DBLoggingProvider.DBLoggingProvider, DotNetNuke.Provider.DBLoggingProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\LoggingProviders\DBLoggingProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </logging>
    <scheduling defaultProvider="DNNScheduler">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="DNNScheduler" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Scheduling.DNNScheduling.DNNScheduler, DotNetNuke.DNNScheduler" providerPath="~\Providers\SchedulingProviders\DNNScheduler\" debug="false" maxThreads="1" />
      </providers>
    </scheduling>
    <friendlyUrl defaultProvider="DNNFriendlyUrl">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="DNNFriendlyUrl" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Url.FriendlyUrl.DNNFriendlyUrlProvider, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" includePageName="true" regexMatch="[^a-zA-Z0-9 _-]" urlFormat="humanfriendly" />
      </providers>
    </friendlyUrl>
    <caching defaultProvider="FileBasedCachingProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="FileBasedCachingProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Cache.FileBasedCachingProvider.FBCachingProvider, DotNetNuke.Caching.FileBasedCachingProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\CachingProviders\FileBasedCachingProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </caching>
    <authentication defaultProvider="ADSIAuthenticationProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="ADSIAuthenticationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Authentication.ActiveDirectory.ADSI.ADSIProvider, DotNetNuke.Authentication.ActiveDirectory" providerPath="~\Providers\AuthenticationProviders\ADSIProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </authentication>
    <members defaultProvider="AspNetMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetMembershipProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Security.Membership.AspNetMembershipProvider, DotNetNuke.Provider.AspNetProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\MembershipProviders\AspNetMembershipProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </members>
    <roles defaultProvider="DNNRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="DNNRoleProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Security.Membership.DNNRoleProvider, DotNetNuke.Provider.DNNProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\MembershipProviders\DNNMembershipProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </roles>
    <profiles defaultProvider="DNNProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="DNNProfileProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Security.Profile.DNNProfileProvider, DotNetNuke.Provider.DNNProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\MembershipProviders\DNNProfileProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </profiles>
    <permissions defaultProvider="CorePermissionProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="CorePermissionProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Security.Permissions.CorePermissionProvider, DotNetNuke.Provider.CorePermissionProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\PermissionProviders\CorePermissionProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </permissions>
    <moduleCaching defaultProvider="FileModuleCachingProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="FileModuleCachingProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.ModuleCache.FileProvider, DotNetNuke.Provider.ModuleCaching.FileProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\ModuleCachingProviders\FileModuleCachingProvider\" />
        <add name="MemoryModuleCachingProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.ModuleCache.MemoryProvider, DotNetNuke.Provider.ModuleCaching.MemoryProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\ModuleCachingProviders\MemoryModuleCachingProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </moduleCaching>
    <outputCaching defaultProvider="FileOutputCachingProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </outputCaching>
    <sitemap defaultProvider="coreSitemapProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="coreSitemapProvider" type="DotNetNuke.SitemapProviders.CoreSitemapProvider, DotNetNuke.SitemapProviders.CoreSitemapProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\MembershipProviders\Sitemap\CoreSitemapProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </sitemap>
  </dotnetnuke>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What version of DNN? What version of ASP.NET? Can you post your web.config (remember to blank out any SQL connection string usernames and passwords)?

Comment: Hey Kev, thanks for the same. some how I am unable to paste it. it says some limit problem. How could I do that ?

Comment: Hi Kev, I just trimmed down by removing comments. please check.. thanks

Comment: You didn't happen to trim anything out of the `<configSections>` section? What version of ASP.NET? What version of DNN?

Comment: No Sir, asp.net version 3.5, DNN version - 5.6.0

Comment: <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^tejgyan.org$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.tejgyan.org/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a small update on this. I used to see the website by setting proxy settings in my browser as the name server weren't changed. Following code was creating a problem removed and resolved the same.

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^tejgyan.org$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.tejgyan.org/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Thanks for the support

Comment: Thanks BGM I just did that